# No apriopriate scroll when changing tableFooterView's frame

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is how I change tableFooterView loaded firstly from storyboard:

[image]

At some time I change `tableFooterView` and assign a newContentSize to `tableView`:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView?.frame.size.height = 400

var newContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize

newContentSize.height += 400
self.tableView.contentSize = newContentSize
```

but it is not working, because scroll ends and tableFooterView is out of scroll. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we change `tableFooterView`'s frame, `the tableView` is not aware of that, so its `contentSize` won't change properly. All it needs to be done is assign completely new `tableFooterView`:

```
let newTableFooterView = self.tableView.tableFooterView
newTableFooterView.frame.size.height = 400

self.tableView.tableFooterView = newTableFooterView
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let newTableFooterView = self.tableView.tableFooterView
newTableFooterView.frame.size.height = 400

self.tableView.tableFooterView = newTableFooterView
```

Re-assign your footer view to the table. The table will recognize it has a new footer and re-do whatever layout needs to occur for the proper size of the footer.